# Tkinter - Entry.get() method does not read the whole content of the entry

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tkinter

I have a specific question concerning the get.()method with Tkinter. Whenever I enter more than one word into the entry field (e.g. dogs AND cats) my script won't work. It only works with one entry (e.g. dogs). My goal is to use the entry field for queries, such as Dogs AND cats OR elephants, etc.

Many thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter import*
import tweepy

master = Tk()
e1 = Entry(master)
Label(master, text="Query").grid(row=0)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

def twitter_search():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(X,Y)
    auth.set_access_token(A,B)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    for item in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_users,
                           q="%s"%(e1.get()),
                            count=50,
                          result_type="recent",
                          include_entities=True,
                          lang="en").items():


print ("\nName:\n" + item.screen_name + "\nLocation:\n" + item.location +"\nDescription:\n" + item.description
              + "\nLink:\n" + "https://www.twitter.com/%s"%item.screen_name)
```

Comment: Call `e1.get()` as a separate step and save it to a variable. I think you'll see that it returns the entire string, contrary to what the question title suggests. The problem isn't with the call to `.get()`.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for your quick reply!
I called e1.get() as a seperate step and saved it to a variable (a). I used that variable in the "for item in tweepy" line -> q=a and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've managed to fix it. Not sure how and why this had an impact on not returning the entire string, but I pulled every single parameter after e1.get()  onto the same line. If you look at my code, it doesn't look 'tidy', especially when it comes to calling e1.get() on an Entry widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can assure you that calling `.get()` on an `Entry` widget (or the variable assigned to it's `textvariable` attribute) will return the entire string.

Please see example below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def callback(*args):
    print(sv.get())
    print(entry.get())

sv = StringVar()

sv.trace("w", callback)

entry = Entry(root, textvariable=sv)

entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Ethan,
Thanks for your quick response! Honestly, it doesn't work. I don't understand why it doesn't return the entire string. My code should work though, or am I missing something?

Comment: I've managed to fix it. Not sure how and why this had an impact on not returning the entire string, but I pulled every single parameter after e1.get()  onto the same line. If you look at my code, it doesn't look 'tidy', especially when it comes to calling e1.get() on an Entry widget

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. what is it exactly that you've changed?

Comment: Apologies for confusing you. Never mind, it still doesn't work. I thought it'd work, but when I tried it for the fifth time, it just stopped working...

Comment: If you still need help with this, I have an email address on my profile. I will reply whenever possible.